# How can i add a bottom navigation to my flutter app without passing it to the home parameter in Material app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i want to use the home parameter to load a different screen but im using it for my bottom navigation, is there a way i can still load my navigation bar but pass something else to the home parameter, my code is here below, i have tried everything

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hotel_search/home_page.dart';
import 'package:hotel_search/splash.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:hotel_search/common/theme.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:hotel_search/start.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:hotel_search/bookings.dart';
import 'package:hotel_search/account.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:hotel_search/model.dart';





void main()async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

 

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() =>  MyAppState();
}

class  MyAppState extends State< MyApp>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
    TabController _controller;
  final List<Widget> tabBarScreens = [
    HomePage(),
    BookScreen(),
    Dashboard(),
     
  ];

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TabController(
        initialIndex: 0, length: tabBarScreens.length, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
   bool ready = false;

    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.black.withAlpha(50),
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light));
    final themeData = HotelConceptThemeProvider.get();
     

  return ChangeNotifierProvider<MyModel>(   
  
  
  create: (context) => MyModel(),
  child: MaterialApp(
      title: 'Hotel Search',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: themeData,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: themeData.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _controller,
          children: tabBarScreens,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
          controller: _controller,
          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
          indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
          isScrollable: false,
          tabs: [
            _buildTabIcon("img/tab_bar_home.svg", 0, themeData),
            _buildTabIcon("img/mooo.svg", 1, themeData),
             _buildTabIcon("img/tab_bar_profile.svg", 2, themeData),
          ],
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {});
          },
        ),

         
        ),
      ));
    
  }
   Widget _buildTabIcon(String assetName, int index, ThemeData themeData) {
    return Tab(
      icon: SvgPicture.asset(
        assetName,
        color: index == _controller.index
            ? Color(0xff008d4b)
            : themeData.primaryColorLight,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Try makin ```home``` a separate widget and then you can pass arguments via Constructor to that.

Comment: im not following you, could you please explain more

Comment: Okay its like this. In your code you are using ```MatrialApp``` and there is ```Scaffold``` in it right? Now simply make a new widget and place all the code of ```Scaffold``` in there. When done, you can pass the Constructor in place of you ```home``` in ```MaterialApp``` right now. Then you can make parameterized constructor to pass values that you like
I hope it make some sense